# dynamically add tab in YiiBooster TbTabs widget

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have created bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs as below, how can I add a new tab dynamically on client side. Is there any event using which I can add new tab just like the "shown" event in below code.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'id' => 'mytabs',
    'type' => 'tabs',
    'tabs' => array(
            array('id' => 'tab1', 'label' => 'Tab 1', 'content' => $this->renderPartial('tab1', null, true), 'active' => true),
            array('id' => 'tab2', 'label' => 'Tab 2', 'content' => 'loading ....'),
            array('id' => 'tab3', 'label' => 'Tab 3', 'content' => 'loading ....'),
    ),
    'events'=>array('shown'=>'js:loadContent')
));?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the new tab link in header, add the new tab, display the new tab

```
$('#tabHeaders').append($('<li><a href="#newtab">New Tab</a></li>'));
$('#tabContent').append($('<div class="tab-pane" id="newtab"></div>'));
$('#newtab').tab('show');
```

Note YiiBooster automatically generates element id, you need to use appropriate jquery selectors

Comment: @ Please take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700642/how-to-add-child-tab-onclick-of-button-in-yii-framework  can we make this tab structure in YiiBooster

Answer (score 1):

There is none but that doesn't mean you can't create it yourself.

Just pass the 'tabs' part via your controller, something like this:

in your **controller**:

```
$tabs => array(
        array('id' => 'tab1', 'label' => 'Tab 1', 'content' => $this->renderPartial('tab1', null, true), 'active' => true),
        array('id' => 'tab2', 'label' => 'Tab 2', 'content' => 'loading ....'),
        array('id' => 'tab3', 'label' => 'Tab 3', 'content' => 'loading ....'),
);

$this->render('pageName', array('tabs' => $tabs));
```

In your **view**:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'id' => 'mytabs',
    'type' => 'tabs',
    'tabs' => $tabs,
    'events'=>array('shown'=>'js:loadContent')
));?>
```

If you want to achieve something similar but in your main layout, you can create a Model which extends from CActiveRecord and stores the tabs in the database. After that you could use a static method in your model class to call and retrieve the tabs. Then in your layout view you can do something like this:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'id' => 'mytabs',
    'type' => 'tabs',
    'tabs' => Model::getTabs(),
    'events'=>array('shown'=>'js:loadContent')
));?>
```

Comment: but what I wanted was dynamic tabs on client side. I have update my question. Your approach is good for server side. Accepting :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's good practice to renderPartial the included views inside the controller.

I found this to work for me in the view:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'type'=>'tabs',
    'tabs'=>array(
        array( //
            'label'=>'Comments ('.$model->commentCount.')',
            'content'=>$this->renderPartial( '_comments', array( 'model'=>$model ), true ),
        ),
    )
));
```

Obviously, for this to work you need "_comments.php" to exist...