# How to add child tab onclick of button in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

Please help to achieve this in Yii framework. onclick of this add button(+ button as showned in image) need to create more tabs.

[image]

I can display tabs by using following code in my View class

```
 <?php 
   $this->widget('CTabView', array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'tab1'=>array(
            'title'=>'Tab1',
            'view'=>'tabs',
            'data'=>array('model'=>BCFormField::model(),),
        ),
)
 )));
?>
```

But let me know how to add more chiltab, onclick of this + button.

Comment: if you are creating new tab, then what will be tab title text? so you need option to add title too? It's not possible. CTabView will load only static tabs. So you can go for some other tools.

Comment: yes i need also name to change dynamically as tab1, tab2, tab3,tab4,.....Can you please refer which one is preferable in Yii?

Comment: You can probably do this by using jQuery

Comment: can i use YUI to achieve this in Yii framework. Bccause YUI has this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to *tricky add tabs* by triggering tabs' visibility.
Create as many as needed tabs (ex. 30) beforehand and set their visibility on certain condition (db field for ex.). 
Then on click you change the key field/variable and a tab gets visible.

See my case:

```
    'tab7'=>array(
        'title'=>Yii::t('general', 'Products / Services'),
        'view'=>'_form_ordercontent',
        'data'=>array('eventId'=>$model->Id),
    'visible' => $model->EventTypeId == DocEvents::TYPE_ORDER || $model->EventTypeId == DocEvents::TYPE_INFLOW || $model->EventTypeId == DocEvents::TYPE_SALE
    ),
    'tab8'=>array(
        'title'=>'Payment',
        'view'=>'_form_payment',
        'data'=>array('model'=>$model, 'eventId'=>$model->Id),
     'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('1');
    ),
```

So as you push button certain variable (or model attribute) gets changed and corresponding tabs get exposed, their content being predefined
Does it fit your case?

Comment: this is ok . But we dont know the user clicks how many times, for every click need to create dynamic tab.

Comment: And Content is not predefined one, need to drag field into this tab and save will be handled

Comment: Isn't it too much? (kind of super-system :-) )

Comment: Hmm. so that now im developing by using YUI library for adding new dynamic tabs

Comment: not bad having YUI, could you share/show then your results?